# How do you keep your application logic hidden if you use backbone.js or ember.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, ember.js

I'm excited to use Backbone.js and Ember.js, but I'm wondering how you can keep your application logic hidden from the user if it's all written in javascript. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing about using javascript libraries like Backbone.js and Ember.js is that your code executed on the client-side (in the browser). To do this, you must deliver the code to the browser, which means your users have a copy. There is no way to "hide" the code from them (there are obfuscation techniques and minimization that can make it difficult, but not impossible).

What you should be doing in Backbone.js or Ember.js is *display* logic. All of your *business logic* of data processing, validation, sanitization, storage happen on your server.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to figure out how best to utilize backbone or ember's routing on top of node. That seems to be a stumbling block for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your server side application should still do *some* processing such as validation, sanitization and sanity checks.